# how to extend home WLAN

Tags: wireless-networking

I am looking to extend my WLAN at home so that I can walk around the house without a noticeable connection break. Reading about this I find the possibility to use access points and repeaters. Access points connect to the wired network and use the same SSID, but a different channel. Repeaters connect to the wireless network and use the same SSID and same channel.

As we are living on 4 floors and each floor is made of concrete with steel there is no sensible place where to put a repeater. I would like to use access points. But when I do this I need to re-connect to WLAN when I change floors. The obvious solution is to create WLANs with different SSID: wlan-floor1, wlan-cellar, wlan-attic and wlan-floor2.

What puzzles me is: I can walk 1000 feet at work without loosing optimal WLAN coverage - all with the same SSID and all without connection interruptions. Any idea how they do this? I am using WPA-PSK, they use an open WLAN with encrypted entry site with password. Are there access points that can share channels? With WPA?

Comment: You should not need to re-connect to the wireless LAN when you change floors. So long as the access points are on the same SSID and are all connected to the same switch (or access point), you should be able to roam seamlessly. How are the access points connected to each other? (Be as specific as possible.)

Comment: You want the same SSID but a different channel all connected to the same wired network. No two adjacent access points should share the same channel. Also refer to http://superuser.com/q/555262/201041

Answer (score 0):

The system (solution) you are describing has multiple service sets, provided by multiple access points, connected by a distribution system. The distribution system is the wired network.

If every access point was set with the same Service Set Identifier (SSID) and authentication information, a WPA key in this case, you will be able to roam seamlessly just like at work. In fact, it is very likely this is essentially the same as they system they have. You can set the Access Points to different channels.

For this solution you would need structured cabling; one outlet for each AP. You would also need a switch that all the access points connect to via the cables. This switch would connect to a router which connects to the internet via your Internet Service Provider(ISP). You might already have a switch and a router in the form of an Integrated Services Router (ISR). This thing, commonly called a "Router" by laypeople, is provided by ISPs for home broadband connections. In other words, just plug the cables into the ethernet ports on the thing that came from the ISP and if there aren't enough ports get one with more.

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: AP = access points

Comment: I forgot to say this solution is called an Extended Service Set (ESS)

Answer (score -2):

Well first off the reason you can walk 1000 feet at work is cause your work has good WiFi with probably about 5 or so repeaters to extended coverage and 2 first to extended you wLan do u have Ethernet if so use and Ethernet cord and plug it into a router on each floor I have this at home cause we have short distance WiFi and in my room I get great reception cause I have a router in it and if u don't have Ethernet which I highly doubt you don't you might be out of luck unless you want to setup more wLan hotspots if the helped please vote it up